# How to convert an integer array to a string without the use of a library

Tags: c, arrays, microcontroller

So I am working on an internship project.

I have to develop a whole system that will gather some data and will then send it through to a server. The system consist of an MSP430G2553 microcontroller so I am coding in pure C without any library's, so no sprintf or malloc functions I can use.

The problem that I am having at the moment is that I have no idea how I am going to send all the data that is in an array to the server at once.

I have the array ADCvalue[20] with 20 values, ranging from 0-350

`ADCvalue[20]= {10, 40, 50, 90, 100, 200, 300, 240, 260, 10, 40, 50, 90, 100, 200, 300, 240, 260, 300, 20}`.

Now I want to send these values all at once with the delimiter "," between every value to the server.
Like this:

```
10,40,50,90,100,200,300,240,260,10,40,50,90,100,200,300,240,260,300,20
```

How can I get the array like this and send it through at once? I already have a print function that can send for example: `char property[] = "property"` as a string.

It would be great if somebody could help me with some psuedo code or some algorithmes to get me started.

Comment: Why not use json?

Comment: I am sending the data through an SMS so I can't real send the data through a json, I think

Comment: Some untested code that you could probably get working for this task: `for (i = 0; i < 20; i++) { sprintf(tempstr,"%d",ADCvalue[i]); strcat(sendval,tempstr); strcat(sendval,","); } sendval[strlen(sendval)-1] = '\0';`

Comment: What is `pure C`? The standard mentions the library functions, FWIW.

Comment: Yh sorry for a the lack of knowledge about C, I am more an infrastructure dude then a programmer but I meant just the basic C programming without using any predefined functions etc.

Comment: @bigbounty how would I go around using JSON? Like how will I put the data in to a JSON object without exceeding the max charater limit of 160 of an sms? Keep in mind that I maybe have to send 2 objects per SMS

Comment: You can format you json object the way you want.It's highly flexible

Answer (score 1):

As you stated not to use any library (for whatever reason), I just wrote a simple `writeIntValue`-function. See the following code which uses this function to write a sequence of positive integral values into a character array. 
Hope it helps.

```
char* writeIntValue(int val, char* dest) {
    // count digits:
    int digits = 0;
    int valCopy = val;
    while (valCopy) {
        digits++;
        valCopy /= 10;
    }

    if (digits == 0)  // means val has been 0
        digits=1; // assume 1 digit to write the '0'-value

    for (int i=digits-1; i>=0; i--) {
        dest[i] = val%10 + '0';
        val/=10;
    }
    dest[digits] = '\0'; // write string-terminating 0x0-value
    return dest + digits; // return a pointer to the end of the value written so far
}

int main() {

    int ADCvalue[20]= {10, 40, 50, 90, 100, 200, 300, 240, 260, 10, 40, 50, 90, 100, 200, 300, 240, 260, 300, 20};

    char buffer[500] = { '\0' };
    char *dest = buffer;
    for (int i=0; i<20; i++) {
        if (i>0)
            *dest++ = ',';
        dest = writeIntValue(ADCvalue[i], dest);
    }
    // buffer here will be "10,40,50,90,100,200,300,240,260,10,40,50,90,100,200,300,240,260,300,20"
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
const char ansitable[10] = {'0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9'};

void procInt(char* buf, int* loc, unsigned short v) {
   if (v == 0) {
      buf[*loc] = '0';
      *loc++; 
      return; 
   }
   unsigned short cv = v;
   unsigned short r;
   unsigned short divid = 1;  
   if (v>9) divid = 10;  
   if (v>99) divid = 100;  
   while (divid > 0) {
      r = cv / divid;
      buf[*loc] = ansitable[r];
      *loc++; 
      cv %= divid;
      divid /= 10;
   }
}

int MAX_SIZE_OF_CHUNCK = 4;

void startWrite(unsigned short* input, int sizeinput) {
   char* buffer = (char *)calloc(sizeinput * MAX_SIZE_OF_CHUNCK, sizeof(char));
   int loc = 0;
   for (int i = 0; i < sizeinput; i++) {
      procInt(buffer, &loc, input[i]);
      if (i < sizeinput-1) {
         buffer[loc] = ',';
         loc++;
      }
   }
   sendToMPU(buffer, loc); //loc - length 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> How can I get the array like this and send it through at once? I
>   already have a print function that can send for example: char
>   property[] = "property" as a string.

Values in the range [0 ... 350] doesn't fit in a single byte, but you can encode those values using pairs of bytes.

An example

```
short int x = 300; /* 0x012C */
```

=

```
unsigned char arr[] = {0x01, 0x2C};
```

or

```
short int x[] = {0x000a, 0x0028, 0x0032, 0x005a, 0x0064, 0x00c8, 0x012c, 0x00f0, 0x0104, 0x000a, 0x0028, 0x0032, 0x005a, 0x0064, 0x00c8, 0x012c, 0x00f0, 0x0104, 0x012c, 0x0014};
```

=

```
unsigned char arr[] = {0x00, 0x0a, 0x00, 0x28, 0x00, 0x32, 0x00, 0x5a, 0x00, 0x64, 0x00, 0xc8, 0x01, 0x2c, 0x00, 0xf0, 0x01, 0x04, 0x00, 0x0a, 0x00, 0x28, 0x00, 0x32, 0x00, 0x5a, 0x00, 0x64, 0x00, 0xc8, 0x01, 0x2c, 0x00, 0xf0, 0x01, 0x04, 0x01, 0x2c, 0x00, 0x14};
```

---

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    short int ADCvalue[] = {10, 40, 50, 90, 100, 200, 300, 240, 260, 10, 40, 50, 90, 100, 200, 300, 240, 260, 300, 20};
    size_t sz = sizeof(ADCvalue) / sizeof(*ADCvalue);
    unsigned char *arr = malloc(sz * 2);

    if (arr == NULL) {
        perror("malloc");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    /* Encode */
    for (size_t i = 0; i < sz; i++) {
        arr[i * 2 + 0] = (unsigned char)(ADCvalue[i] >> 8);
        arr[i * 2 + 1] = (unsigned char)(ADCvalue[i] & 0xFF);
    }
    /* Send array */
    /* .. */
    /* Decode */
    for (size_t i = 0; i < sz; i++) {
        printf("%d\n", (arr[i * 2] << 8) | (arr[i * 2 + 1]));
    }
    return 0;
}
```